# CSS images and text won't scale with @media queries

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am designing welcome page for a local non-profit. I am trying my first responsive site, so its kind of a hodge-podge of code. Here's [a link](http://www.lingulo.com/tutorials/css/how-to-build-a-html5-website-from-scratch) to the tutorial I was following to make this happen. I have a hunch that the problem is solely within the CSS. The tutorial has me include a reset.css file to reset all HTML styles.

The problem I'm having is that **1)** images and text won't scale using @media and images seem to duplicate in various sizes when viewing on ios. **2)** The @font-face and text elements don't work when I combine all CSS into one external style sheet. **3)** The h1 text is cut off when viewed in Chrome. **4)** The Submit button defaults to the browser default on smaller sizes.

Here is the site: http://www.dubuquedreamcenter.com/

**Thank you very much. I appreciate any help I can get to learn this better.**

Answer (score 2):

> 1) images and text won't scale with @media queries

To scale images, put them in container `<div>`'s with a percentage width. Then set `max-width: 100%` on the images.

Unfortunately it's not possible to scale text with media queries. You have to manually adjust the `font-size` at each breakpoint.

> ...images seem to duplicate in various sizes when viewing on ios

You're loading your logo in the HTML but then also as a background image at smaller viewports. Hide the HTML version in the media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 783px) {
  #logo img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

> 2) The @font-face and text elements don't work when I combine all CSS
>   into one external style sheet

Seems to work fine for me when I add the `@font-face` rules to the top of your main stylesheet.

> 3) The h1 text is cut off when viewed in Chrome

The `<h1>` text appears fine to me in Chrome 29.

> 4) The Submit button defaults to the browser default on smaller sizes.

I'm not seeing that either, but most likely you don't have the custom button styles set in all of your media queries.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggestions from [cantera25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/723007/cantera25), in the head of your page your have:

```
...  
<title>Dubuque Dream Center</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/ddc_styles2.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/reset.css">  
....
```

Start by reversing this order, you always call the reset.css script first.

Once you do that there's no reason why you couldn't put the css styles you have in the head of the page into ddc_styles2.css